# Transit visa required in Muscat

Tags: visas, transit, canadian-citizens, oman

I am a Canadian doing a visa run from Doha.  I have a return trip booked on Qatar Airways, arriving in Muscat at 1415 with the return flight leaving Muscat at 1735.  Am I able to proceed directly through to the transit area and remain airside?

Comment: Simple to get an eVisa online to be safe if you can stay airside, can also get a visa on arrival but eVisa will save you time to get back on your return flight.

Answer (score 1):

In March 2018, the Omani government announced that applications for tourist visas, including express visas, can only be made online through http://evisa.rop.gov.om, and "will not be received at the visa service desks." Previously, visa on arrival could be obtained at either an airport or border post, through the e-visa system.

[image]